# How can I fetch values from specific signals from a single CAN message in capl script?

Tags: can-bus, capl, canoe

For example I have a can message "A" which has signals 1,2,3,4,5,6....
Now, I only want to fetch values from signals 3,5 and 6. How can I do that in a smarter way?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do it. Kindly post your approach.